# pgadmin4 query tool always comes back not connected

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Q: How can I diagnose and correct problems with the Query tool connection.

Using pgAdmin4 1.0-rc1 to connect to a local host "PostgreSQL 9.5.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 18..."

I can connect and drill down to my schema. I use the context menu to select 'Query tool'. The editor shows the correct database@host:port in the editor header bar.

When I execute a simple query, or any query
  select 1 as first;

I get the message 
"Not conencted to the server or the connection to the server has been closed.

instead of the expected results.

The editor alwa

Comment: The query tool opens a second connection to the database; looks like something went wrong there. Turn `log_connections` and `log_disconnections` to `on` in `postgresql.conf`, run `pg_ctl reload`, try again and see what the PostgreSQL log file says.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved now,
Upgrade pgAdmin4 to version 1.3. https://www.pgadmin.org/download/

Comment: Version 1.3 doesn't work for me. I installed it with PostgreSQL 9.6.2 right now on 64-bit Windows 7 using [this installer](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads#windows). `SELECT 1 as first` query works but when I try to create a table the same error occurred: `CREATE DATABASE "geobase_dev" WITH OWNER = postgres ENCODING = "UTF8" LC_COLLATE = "en_US.UTF-8" LC_CTYPE = "en_US.UTF-8";`. There were no problems in PgAdmin 3 with it.

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is wrap the schema, table, column names with double quotation marks in every sentence.

Comment: OP said even a query that doesn't have any of table, schema or column names fails

Comment: Give an example, please

Comment: `select 1 as first`