# pgadmin4 query tool always shows message not connected

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

Q: How can I diagnose and correct problems with the Query tool connection.

Using pgAdmin4 1.0-rc1 to connect to a local host "PostgreSQL 9.5.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 18..."

In the browser pane I can connect and drill down to my schema. I use the context menu to select 'Query tool'. The editor shows the correct database@host:port in the editor header bar.

When I execute this sample query
  select 1 as first;

I get the message tab showing
"Not connected to the server or the connection to the server has been closed.

instead of a simple grid showing
  first
      1

Same message shows for any query, and the time it takes to come back with the message seems to be too long, especially since I'm using a localhost.

The same query works fine in phpPgAdmin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pgadmin4 query tool always comes back not connected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325567/pgadmin4-query-tool-always-comes-back-not-connected)

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: I have the same issue and my workaround was to use pgAdmin 3...
This started all of a sudden, it worked perfectly the day before.

Comment: Could you update to current version (it is 1.1 as of today)? Does it still happen?

Comment: I have v1.1 and get this too "Not connected to the server or the connection to the server has been closed.". Got it when I did a create table command. However when I do "select 1 as first", it runs fine. Or when I manually create a table with the gui and do a select on it. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This was an error in 1.0.

1.1 and 1.2 have corrected this.

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade to latest version pgAdmin4(1.3), This issue has been resolved now.

https://www.pgadmin.org/download/